# Server Side Ajax configuration for Angular-datatables for GET Request

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm using Angular version 5. I need to do Server Side for angular-datatables. It works with POST request but I'm unable to do it with GET request.

There's a sample API (https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/), It gives same response for GET and POST request. Angular-datatables does server-side for POST but not GET.

Here's a code example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/visible-columns-with-serverside-loading-angular-way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it working. I needed to send datatables info via request params. Here's what I did.

```
 this.dtOptions = {
      paging: true,
      lengthChange: false,
      searching: true,
      pageLength: 10,
      columnDefs: [{ targets: 3, orderable: false }],
      pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
      order: [[0, 'desc']],
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        const params = this.objectToHttpParams(dataTablesParameters);
        console.log('params', params);

        this.http
          .get(
            'http://myapi.com',
            {
              params: params,
              headers: new HttpHeaders().set(
                'token',
                localStorage.getItem('token')
              )
            }
          )
          .subscribe(resp => {

            this.result = resp['data'];

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp['length'],
              recordsFiltered: resp['length'],
              data: []
            });
          });
      }
    };

// Helper Function
 objectToHttpParams(obj: any) {
    return Object.entries(obj || {}).reduce((params, [key, value]) => {
      return params.set(
        key,
        isObjectLike(value) ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value)
      );
    }, new HttpParams());
  }
```

With these options, I'm able to make it work with GET requests and also send HTTP Params and Headers instead of sending in body.

Comment: Thanks for this. FYI, I have also made this work by using     
`params : dataTablesParameters`. I followed yours at first but I could not find away to initialize `objectToHttpParams`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

[Example reference](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way)

```
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        const params = {};
        this.objectToHttpParams(params , dataTablesParameters , '');
        this.http
          .get(
            'http://myapi.com,
            {
              params: params,
               headers: new HttpHeaders().set(
                'token',
                localStorage.getItem('token')
              )
            }
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            this.result = resp['data'];

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp['length'],
              recordsFiltered: resp['length'],
              data: []
            });
          });
      },


  objectToHttpParams(params: any, data: any, currentPath: string) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (data[key] instanceof Object) {
          if (currentPath !== '' ) {
            this.objectToHttpParams(params, data[key], `${currentPath}[${key}]`);
          } else {
            this.objectToHttpParams(params, data[key], `${currentPath}${key}`);
          }
        } else {
            if (currentPath !== '' ) {
              params[`${currentPath}[${key}]`] = data[key];
            } else {
              params[`${currentPath}${key}`] = data[key];
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

Verified and adjusting a couple of things, I was able to replicate the behavior of the native datatable parameters when the serverside parameter is present
[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61725005/4024336)