# Angular Http Client - How to Pass Nested Params Object to GET API

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am using latest version of angular (8). I am doing a conversion of my Http request from the original http to the new http client. I am calling a GET API where I am sending a nested params in the following way:

```
let data: any = {filters: {"4e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f": "465c1ab-2b89-4b51-8a7b-5d2ac862ee32"}, is_indexed: true}
return this.httpClient.get<Register[]>('/registers/', {headers: headers, params: data});
```

The above code, the nested params are not recognised. How do I properly pass as nested params using the HttpClient? Ps In the old Http, there was no issue using the above code. Thanks for the help in advance.

**UPDATE**
Url would look similar to this:

https://www.somepapi.com/registers/?filters=%7B%224e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f%22:%228465c1ab-2b89-4b51-8a7b-5d2ac862ee32%22%7D&is_indexed=true;

Comment: have you tried to pass param:data using `let params = new HttpParams();`

Comment: and one thing pass value as string in data. change this `is_indexed:true` to `is_indexed:"true" ` JSON.stringify() `could help you though.

Comment: What is the structure of the query string you want? Could you include the sample of the desired url.

Comment: This documentation can help you further https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings/#httpparamssetnbsp

Comment: Example url (not same but similar to example ) https://api.example.com/registers/06a00c0d-ae70-47a1-a3e2-c3288ab234cc?filters=%7B%224e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f%22:%2223473473-7938-4faa-997a-8310516a0655%22,%220773f612-b619-4a0d-9dd7-280f926e4c38%22:%2223473473-7938-4faa-997a-8310516a0655%22%7D&is_indexed=true

Answer (score 4):

You could recursively iterate through the data object to flatten it out.

```js
getData(data: any) {
  let params = {};    

  this.buildHttpParams(params, data, "");

  return this.httpClient.get("...", {params: params})
}

private buildHttpParams(params: any, data: any, currentPath: string) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (data[key] instanceof Object) {
            this.buildHttpParams(params, data[key], `${currentPath}${key}.`);
        } else {
            params[`${currentPath}${key}`] = data[key];
        }
    });
}
```

This will change our data object from:

```js
{
  filters: {
    "4e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f": "465c1ab-2b89-4b51-8a7b-5d2ac862ee32"
  },
  "is_indexed": true
}
```

to:

```js
{
  "filters.4e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f": "465c1ab-2b89-4b51-8a7b-5d2ac862ee32",
  "is_indexed": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working method of passing nested objects in Angular by serializing with `JSON.stringify`:

```
const stringifiedParams = JSON.stringify(this.filterParams);
return this.http.get<any[]>(`jobs`, {params: {filter: stringifiedParams}});
```

In Node this deserializes the params with `JSON.parse`:

```
filter = JSON.parse(req.query.filter.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use qs to stringify your object to url query string and then use the native fromString import on HttpParams constructor

```
let data: any = {filters: {"4e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f": "465c1ab-2b89-4b51-8a7b-5d2ac862ee32"}, is_indexed: true}

const params = new HttpParams({fromString: qs.stringify(data)});

return this.httpClient.get<Register[]>('/registers/', {headers: headers, params});
```

Work fine for me with complex object.

See https://npmjs.com/package/qs and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/qs

Answer (score 1):

After many searching, I think that there is no way to pass nested json object to get api. Nethertheless, I have a solution for when your webservice is build with spring boot. Here is what you can do.

**At the angular side**
*I sugest you to encode your json query to base64 to shorten it:*

```js
let data: any = {filters: {"4e9bc554-db54-4413-a718-b89ffdb91c2f": "465c1ab-2b89-4b51-8a7b-5d2ac862ee32"}, is_indexed: true}

let objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(data);
let objJsonB64 = btoa(objJsonStr);
let queryParams = new HttpParams();
queryParams = queryParams.append('q', objJsonB64);

return this.httpClient.get<Register[]>('/registers/', {headers: headers, params: queryParams});
```

**At the spring boot side:**
Create a servletRequest mapper that will help to transform you query and inject  in the body

```js
package com.example.ws.servlet;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.servlet.ReadListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class SeachQueryHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";
    
    private boolean loaded;

    public SeachQueryHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (loaded) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Already loaded!");
        }

        var query = getRequest().getParameter("q");
        var decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(query);
        var decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
        
        try (var body = new BodyInputStream(decodedString.getBytes(getCharacterEncoding()))) {
            loaded = true;
            return body;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getCharacterEncoding() {
        return CHARSET;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * The exact copy of 
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.function.DefaultServerRequestBuilder$BodyInputStream
     */
    private static class BodyInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

        private final InputStream delegate;

        public BodyInputStream(byte[] body) {
            this.delegate = new ByteArrayInputStream(body);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return this.delegate.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            return this.delegate.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            return this.delegate.read(b);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            return this.delegate.skip(n);
        }

        @Override
        public int available() throws IOException {
            return this.delegate.available();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            this.delegate.close();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
            this.delegate.mark(readlimit);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
            this.delegate.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean markSupported() {
            return this.delegate.markSupported();
        }
    }
}
```

*Add a filter to transform your request*

```js
package com.example.ws.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.example.ws.servlet.SeachQueryHttpServletRequestWrapper;

@Configuration
public class SeachQueryFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
            ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterchain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
                
        var query = request.getParameter("q");

        if( query != null ) {
            var wrapper = new SeachQueryHttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
            filterchain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
        }else {
            filterchain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

**And voilà!**

Answer (score -1):

Your solution should be implemented like this now:

```
import { HttpClient,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

let params: any = new HttpParams();

// Begin assigning parameters
params = params.append('filters', {"4e9bc554-db54": "23473473-7938", "555555-db54": "33333-7938"});
params = params.append('is_indexed', true);
return this.httpClient.get<Register[]>('/registers/', {headers: headers, { params });
```

Other than this there's a set property too, you can check further in the Angular's Documentation.

Comment: yeah just tested it doesn't work. 'filters' expects a string a value and when I stringify it, the API doesn't recognise it as a nested object but string value

Comment: I'll check this in few hours and get back to you